# Приведение Number[] к Double[] выдает ClassCastException

Tags: java, исключения

Почему не приводится `Number[]` к `Double[]`?

```
Double[] resultArray = (Double[]) DEFAULT_NUMBER_ARRAY;
```

Ведь `Double` является подклассом класса `Number`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Number; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
at com.lugowoy.helper.filling.array.numbers.FillingArrayDoubleRandomNumbers.fill(FillingArrayDoubleRandomNumbers.java:50)
at com.lugowoy.helper.filling.array.numbers.FillingArrayDoubleRandomNumbers.fill(FillingArrayDoubleRandomNumbers.java:26)
at com.lugowoy.helper.filling.array.numbers.FillerArrayNumbers.fill(FillerArrayNumbers.java:42)
at com.lugowoy.helper.filling.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Comment: Про прив**и**дение можете почитать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). P.S. не удержался) исправьте тему, плз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное свойство называется ковариантностью. С [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Ковариантностью называется сохранение иерархии наследования исходных
> типов в производных типах в том же порядке. Так, если класс Cat
> наследуется от класса Animal, то естественно полагать, что
> перечисление IEnumerable будет потомком перечисления
> IEnumerable. Действительно, «список из пяти кошек» — это
> частный случай «списка из пяти животных». В таком случае говорят, что
> тип (в данном случае обобщённый интерфейс) IEnumerable ковариантен
> своему параметру-типу T.

(В вашем случае Cat - это Double, Animal - это Number, IEnumetable - это массив)

Если говорить совсем просто, то можно рассуждать так - у вас есть массив из Number (каких угодно) и вы его хотите скастить к массиву Double. У вас этого сделать не получиться, потому что не всякий Number - это Double. Например, у вас в массиве Number'ов будет лежать Integer, и тогда все будет очень плохо.

Обратная ситуация сработает - у вас есть массив Double и вы его кастите к массиву Number. Т.е. каждый Double - это Number, то у вас все будет хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

Коротко: подозреваю, что `Double[]` не является наследником `Number[]`

---

Если выполнить такой код:

```
System.out.println(Number[].class);
System.out.println(Double[].class);
System.out.println(Number.class);
System.out.println(Double.class);
```

то в ответ мы получим:

```
class [Ljava.lang.Number;
class [Ljava.lang.Double;
class java.lang.Number
class java.lang.Double
```

тут важны первые 2 символа в имени классов массивов, это совсем другие классы, не `Number` и `Double`. Подозреваю, т.к. исходников не нашел, что `Double[]` не является наследником `Number[]` поэтому и привидение не работает.

---

В данном случае вам поможет простое перекидывание массива из одного в другой. Там вы уже будете обращаться к `Number`, который возможно будет принадлежать `Double`

Comment: Это называется ковариантность. Почитать можно в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#Java)